# Oracle Escape Special Characters in Substitution Variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a SQL script for use in SQL plus using substitution variables defined at runtime.  Is there a way to actively escape any special characters coming in?

For instance, if the variable has an ' in it, it will immediately break whatever line in the script is running it with a

```
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
```

error since I didn't complete the quote or completed it too early.  I just want it to treat the variable as a string.  Is there a way to tell Oracle to just treat the characters literally to set a field or similar?

In my specific case, I want to make a general case script to change a password by prompting for the user, old, and new password.

```
connect &&myuser/&&oldpass@mydb;
alter user &&myuser identified by &&newpass replace &&oldpass;
```

If the old or new password contains special characters, it could break for a plethora of reasons, including the issue I have above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to escape characters in substitution variable values.

SQL*Plus substitution variables (those of type `CHAR`, the only other types are numeric) [are always substituted verbatim](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables#6_3).  SQL*Plus pays no attention to the structure of the statements in which substitution variables appear: it just does a search-and-replace of the variables with their values, irrespective of whether doing that leaves a valid SQL statement afterwards.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a better way to take in the values or should I just be going about password maintenance in another way?  I'm not in a DBA position, but I'm required to reset my password every X days, and I'd like a better way than going into each connection one by one and resetting them.  Would you have any suggestions or is this off topic now?

Comment: Try surrounding the passwords with `"` characters (e.g. `alter user &&myuser identified by "&&newpass" replace "&&oldpass";`).  You can't have a `"` character in a password, and (as far as I know) you can put any characters other than `"` in a `"..."` string, so you should probably be okay.